# How to explicitly save or close a recordset when a form deactivates?

Tags: forms, ms-access, recordset

I apologize if this is too vague a question, but we're having the following problem:
We use a search form to find a record, then load it in a bound-control form where changes are made. Then we return to the search form and open another record. When we do that, the form's BeforeUpdate property fires a 3020 error, "Update without Add New or Edit" and stepping through the code it's referring to the FIRST opened record. This is strange because there is no explicit update call, but after much trial and error I think the error is thus:

Record #1 is opened via the form and changes are made. Record #2 is opened on that same form without closing the first recordset. Even though we now re-opened the form with the second record, Access still assumes we're editing record 1, i.e. that we're trying to edit 2 records concurrently. Same as though we had a datasheet form and we edited one row and then tried to edit a second row without saving the first. What I want to be able to do is have it automatically do an update on the first record when the form deactivates so loading a new record doesn't cause this conflict.

So the bottom line is this: **Is there a way, on say the form's Dirty or Deactivate event, that we can force the form's recordset to update and close ** before loading a second record?

I hope I made this clear enough, it's a complex problem, so any small guidance would help. Btw, you may ask, "Why are you running the same code to open the same form twice?" Good question! Hey it's an old and badly written app (the thing has GoSubs in it for Pete's sake) but I have no choice but to make the best of a bad situation.

EDIT: I was asked to post code, which is reasonable, but it's in several different places. So I have the data form, it has a "Search" button to go back to the search form for opening another record. The search button on the data entry form is:

```vb
    Private Sub CommandSearch_Click()
      On Error GoTo Err_CommandSearch_Click
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Reference Form", acNormal 'This is the form that does the searching

    Exit_CommandSearch_Click:
      Exit Sub

    Err_CommandSearch_Click:
      MsgBox Err.Description
      Resume Exit_CommandSearch_Click
    End Sub
```

When a record is selected on that search form, then the new form is opened with this code. Now this is where it gets tricky. I'm not the original programmer, as I said I think it was written in Access 97 by someone after taking an hour to read "Access for Dummies" :). But it always looks like only one copy of the form is open, so maybe it's re-opening it?

```vb
Public Sub CommandLoadCase_Click()
  Dim LoadUTUCaseNumber As String, lengthUTUCaseNumber As Integer


  lengthUTUCaseNumber = InStr(Forms![Reference Form]![Reference Query SubForm]![UTU Case Number], "-") - 1
  If (lengthUTUCaseNumber = 0) Then
    LoadUTUCaseNumber = ""
  Else
    LoadUTUCaseNumber = Left$(Forms![Reference Form]![Reference Query SubForm]![UTU Case Number], lengthUTUCaseNumber)
  End If
  On Error Resume Next
  Forms![Case Appeal_Add-On Form].UTUCaseKeyToFind = LoadUTUCaseNumber
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Case Appeal_Add-On Form", acNormal, , , , , LoadUTUCaseNumber
  'Case Appeal Add On Form referred to here is the data entry form I refer to above.
End Sub
```

Finally, the Error 3020 (Update without Add/Edit) is occurring after it executes this line on the data entry form. (I know the code is complicated which is why I didn't enter it at first).

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 [UTU Claim Sequence Key] = [UTU Claim Alpha Sequence] & CStr([UTU Claim Numeric Sequence])
End Sub
```

Comment: A record is committed when: 1) table/query/bound form is closed; 2) move to another record; 3) execute code to save. You open multiple instances of same form? I know this is possible but I have never utilized it. How many instances of form - only 2, why only 2 and not more? If this is an old app, has this code been working? What changed? Why don't you eliminate this approach and instead use one instance of form and apply filter? Edit question to post code.

Comment: Without code, impossible to say what's going on. You should also mention which version of Access you're using. You could try to add a button to your form and put this code in the on-click event to explicitly save your changes: **If Me.dirty Then Me.Dirty = False**

Comment: Add your code and the error producing line with the error.

Comment: @Rene I thought about that If Me.Dirty... line, but if I explicitly set Dirty to false, won't that undo any changes made? If not, then I think that's my answer.

Comment: @Rene, also I'm using 32-bit Access 2016. However, I have no idea what the original Access version it's written was. I'm told it's 20 years old, probably slapped together over the years.

Comment: @June7. Good question. I don't know if it's multiple instances of the same form. The program is REALLY strangely written. The form is not closed before searching for another record. However, when loading the second record, there is still only one instance of the form apparently open. As for the code working, I'm told it did BEFORE we migrated the data to SQL Server. I know the two handle data and record locks differently. Assuming what's happening is that opening record #2 makes Access think it's changing/saving data to #2 while #1 is still open.

Comment: @David, by setting Dirty to False you force MS Access to save the current record.

Comment: Code reveals using default instance, but not using filter. Show Form_Load event of `Case Appeal_Add-On Form`where the OpenArgs is used (LoadUTUCaseNumber). `FormOpen` on a already opened form without filter won't change recordd, what save data usually.passes new openargs. Close form before open again or use `Form.Dirty = False`.

Comment: User should not be allowed to return to search form without first quitting the data edit form. Instead of using OpenArgs, apply filter with OpenForm WHERE CONDITION argument.